# SqlDataSource throwing "Specified cast is not valid" error on data pulled from Oracle

Tags: asp.net, oracle, sqldatasource

This SqlDataSource, which is pulling from an Oracle db, throws "Specified cast is not valid" ONLY when I include `c.item_cost` in the SQL. If I remove this column, no error. It does not matter if I actually reference the field in code.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="mySqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" ProviderName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" 
     SelectCommand="select msi.segment1 partnumber, 
                           msi.description, 
                           msi.primary_uom_code uom, 
                           c.item_cost
                    from apps.cst_item_costs c, apps.mtl_system_items_b msi, APPS.ORG_ORGANIZATION_DEFINITIONS org
                         and msi.organization_id=org.ORGANIZATION_ID
                         and c.organization_id=org.ORGANIZATION_ID
                         and c.cost_type_id=1 
                         and  ((msi.inventory_item_id=c.inventory_item_id) 
                         and (msi.organization_id=c.organization_id))  
                    order by msi.segment1">
```

Also, if I add SQL to trim the number of rows down to a small number, the error is NOT thrown. I'm guessing it's some piece of data in the column causing the issue.

Is the SqlDataSource making some assumptions on datatypes?

Even if I can pinpoint the data, which appears to all be valid decimals, how can this error be avoided?

Please let me know if more information is needed. I am currently trying to pinpoint the data that causes this but everything appears to be a valid decimal though some have more digits. The SQL does successfully run with a db tool such as TOAD.

**Update:** The value in the `c.item_cost` is 15.032221226116 which is far more decimal digits than other data.

Comment: might be translation of types from Oracle to .Net  Do you really need all the precision for the price?  Does ROUND(c.item_cost,6) throw the error?

Comment: @kevinsky It works. At the same time, I could ROUND(c.item_cost,12) and it still works. Not up to me how far I can round but you've got me moving. Write it up and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem involving conversion of Oracle data types to .Net types.  Entity Framework 3 and 4 had a similar problem.  If you specified an Oracle type as Number(10) it was interpreted as a .Net [Float](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#).

I suspect this is a similar issue with .Net casting the Oracle number into a float instead of a decimal.  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net) has more details.

I recommend trying ROUND(c.item_cost,12)  or even CAST(c.item_cost as DECIMAL(3,12)) as item_cost

Comment: Yes, item_cost is a `Number` type